# Magento saving a product option for an attribute with a dropdown type

Tags: magento

I have written code that automatically imports products basically something like:

```
$product->setName('my name');
$product->save();
```

This is fine for free fill text boxes, but how would I go about setting say manufacturer, which is a drop down menu? Is there also a way that if the option doesnt exist, then it will automagically add it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tested in 1.5.0.1, you just need to target the correct attribute ID.  As @B00MER stated, the attribute will not be created that you are targetting but if the attribute exist, this will create the options.

```
$eav_entity_setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$new_option['attribute_id'] = $id;
$new_option['value']['_custom_'.$value][0] = $value;
$eav_entity_setup->addAttributeOption($new_option);
```

Documentation about addAttributeOption can be found here.
http://freegento.com/doc/d0/d7b/_eav_2_model_2_entity_2_setup_8php-source.html#l00603

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/catalog/adding_a_new_attribute_option

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create the functionality yourself unfortunately.  And by default Magento will not 'automagically' create a option if one doesn't pre-exist.

To simply set the ID of the value you want (Say Sony was ID 12) you can do:

`$product->setData('mfr', '12');`

However you may find a lot more insight here on steps to do what your looking for:

http://www.arscommunity.com/wiki/magento/configurable-products-creation-code